# Axon 4 - Kafka ext 4.0.RC3 gives start up error

Tags: axon

Got below setup and it works perfectly fine when 4.0-RC2 version is used.

Howver it gives startup error when we we try to use latest version 4.0.RC3.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
A component required a bean named 'kafkaMessageSource' that could not be found.
```

**build.gradle**

```
compile "org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.0-RC3"
        configurations { compile.exclude module: 'axon-server-connector' }
        compile group: 'org.axonframework.extensions.kafka', name: 'axon-kafka', version: '4.0-RC3'
        compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.0.1'
```

**application.yml (command)**

```
axon:
  snapshot:
    trigger:
      treshold:
        order: 100
  kafka:
    default-topic: order-events
    producer:
      retries: 5
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      transaction-id-prefix: order-tx
    consumer:
      group-id: kafka-group,kafka-group2
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  distributed:
    enabled: true
  serializer:
    messages: xstream
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      command-processor:
        mode: tracking
        source: kafkaMessageSource
```

**application.yml(projection)**

```
axon:
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      kafka-group:
        mode: tracking
        source: kafkaMessageSource
  kafka:
    default-topic: order-events
    consumer:
      group-id: kafka-group
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes between RC2 and RC2 of the [Kafka Extension](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka) provided by Axon are not compatible. This choice was made to have the freedom to adjust the API according to further findings. Hence why it's a release candidate and not a final release. This is stated on the GitHub page of the project **and** on the [reference guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/kafka) page on the Kafka Extension.

Configuration properties used in RC2 are thus **not** compatible with RC3. Check the reference guide (which has been expanded together with RC3) for more specifics on how to adjust your config.

Comment: So RC3 version is not settled one and we need to wait till final release for complete adoption.

Comment: It's indeed not the final version yet, but nothing is holding you back for using it. Actually, for the team it would be highly beneficial if you use it, as that's a good way to figure out whether major adjustments still need to be made to improve the structure of it. But since  it's a release candidate that does mean the API might still change, albeit slightly. Pretty sure the current set up is further in the required direction and that a following release of the extension would be a final one.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to incompatible source code - version.
Would stick to 4.0.RC2 version.